# run commands as another user or change user Linux shell script remote execution from windows

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, winscp, plink

I am new to linux world. So please excuse for any stupid questions.

I have a linux machine and I don’t have root access. I have service account which have full access to app folder. My login (ssh) credentials don’t have access to that app folder.

So I will follow the below process.

1)  Copy the app folder in windows machine to /tmp/ in linux using winscp.

2)  Login to the machine using putty.

3)  Change the user to service account using below command.

```
sudo su – “service account”
```

4)  Then I will copy app files from /tmp/ folder to /app/ folder and start the other configurations.

I want to automate the above process. So for I did below.

```
#Copy files to tmp folder

 winscp.com -hostkey=* user:"password"@host /command "put D:/app_folder/ /tmp/ app_folder"

#Execute the script remotely

 plink user:@host -m D:\Install_app.sh
```

The above script is running fine until I run test echo commands. It is started throwing errors when I run configuration commands due to user don’t have access to app folder. Only service account has access. But service account doesn’t have remote login access. So I can’t run the script with service account.

So I tried to run commands inside the script with service account. I tried below

```
Echo “password” | sudo –S su - “service account” “commands”
```

It is not working. Could you please let me know is there any other way to achieve this. I want to change user inside the script, once script start executing.

Note: The process is following by linux admin team due to security reason. So I can’t change the process :(.